# Why can't I mock `crypto.createHash`?

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to test a function which makes use of Node's `crypto.createHash` function. However, when I try to mock it using `jest.mock('crypto', () => ({ createHash: … }))`, the mock doesn't seem to work.

The unit under test uses both `Hash#update` and `Hash#digest`, so I'm trying to add those to the `createHash` mock, but when the unit runs, `createHash` returns `undefined`.

##### `src/hash.ts`

```js
import { createHash } from 'crypto';

export function hash(input: string | Uint8Array): Uint8Array {
  return new Uint8Array(createHash('sha512').update(input).digest().buffer);
}
```

##### `src/__test__/hash.test.ts`

```js
import { createHash } from 'crypto';

import { hash } from '../hash-node.js';

const mockDigest = jest.fn();

jest.mock('crypto', () => ({
  createHash: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
    update: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    digest: mockDigest,
  }),
}));

describe('hash', () => {
  it('uses SHA512', () => {
    hash('foo');

    expect(createHash).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      expect.stringMatching(/sha512/i),
    );
  });
});
```

##### Output

```
    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'update')

      3 |
      4 | export function hash(input: string | Uint8Array): Uint8Array {
    > 5 |   return new Uint8Array(createHash('sha512').update(input).digest().buffer);
        |                         ^
      6 | }
      7 |

      at hash (src/hash.ts:4:25)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/__test__/hash.test.ts:16:5)
```

As you can see, `createHash` is clearly returning `undefined`, as though `.mockReturnValue` hadn't been called.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get this module mock to work?

Comment: It works fine for me. Do you have a `__mocks__` directory?

Comment: No. At this point, just the module and test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came back to this and was able to figure it out; it's a result of configuring Jest to reset mocks between tests. Once I moved the `mockReturnValue` call on `createHash` to inside a `beforeEach` block, it all started working as expected.

```js
import { type Hash, createHash } from 'crypto';

import { hash } from '../hash.js';

const mockDigest = jest.fn();

jest.mock('crypto', () => ({
  createHash: jest.fn(),
}));

describe('hash', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    (createHash as jest.MockedFunction<typeof createHash>).mockReturnValue({
      update: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
      digest: mockDigest,
    } as unknown as Hash);
  });

  it('uses SHA512', () => {
    hash('foo');

    expect(createHash).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      expect.stringMatching(/sha512/i),
    );
  });
});
```